# Highlighting source code on my blog article

Tags: blogger

I write articles on my blog and I need to highlight the source code(java, php or whatever) with special colors like here in `stackoverflow` with the `<pre>` tag; could you tell me what option should i use in my blog to do so? You can take a look on my [blog](http://sweettutos.blogspot.com/) to see what I mean. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

StackOverflow uses [Google Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/)

For the most basic usage, just decorate your `pre` tags with the `PrettyPrint` class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Syntax Highliter code to  highlight your code in the blog posts. For this you need to install some code in blogger editHtml page you should add the syntaxHighlither code in blogger template.

Afger posting posts in your blog if any html or java code come then you need to convert it escaped code.

Major issue with this method is that all right angle brackets must be HTML escaped, eg all `<` must be replaced with `&lt;` This will ensure correct rendering.

[Configure SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/manual/installation.html) in your blog.

Answer (score 0):

If you use IntellIJ you can export as HTML which is really nice and works for me.